# Does anyone know if Angie's List is using an off-the-shelf CMS or is their website proprietary?

Tags: cms

I was wondering if anyone here knows what [Angies's List](http://angieslist.com) is based on?  I am looking for a CMS to use for an upcoming project, and am impressed with their site.  If they are using an off-the-shelf CMS then I'd like to consider it.

If they're using proprietary software (or is built in-house) well then that's that.

Comment: For what it's worth, from the HTTP headers and the use of `.aspx` extensions you can tell that they use Microsoft ASP.Net

Comment: The accepted answer was supported by facts, and the question itself asked a definite question that had but one answer possible. Closing it as "not constructive" is patently ridiculous. Soliciting debate? Nonsense.  The only debate possible for the question is how inappropriate the reason for closing it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a few pages, their source code includes:

```
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
```

and

```
<span>Powered by <a href="http://drupal.org">Drupal</a></span>  </div>
```

,which leads be to believe its [Drupal.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drupal-net/) since standard Drupal is PHP not .NET. I thought maybe they used to be PHP and switched, but checking their [internet archive](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20030801000000%2a/http://www.angieslist.com) all the way back to 2003 they have always been using asp(x) pages. If you look at the first screenshot of Drupal.NET, it looks almost identical to the angieslist template.

Also I found this snippet on their contact page:

```
<a href="http://rightnow.com/cx.html" target="_blank"  title="Powered By RightNow Technologies">
<span class="rn_ScreenReaderOnly">Powered By RightNow Technologies</span></a>
```

**Edit**

This is very interesting... if you do a header check on a normal page you get:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK =>
Cache-Control => private
Content-Type => text/html; charset=utf-8
Server => Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version => 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By => ASP.NET
Content-Length => 25475
Date => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 22:47:43 GMT
Connection => close
Set-Cookie => ALREG-1=exp=10/4/2012 6:47:44 PM&memType=2; domain=.angieslist.com; expires=Sat, 04-Oct-2014 22:47:44 GMT; path=/
```

I found if the url has invalid without a trailing slash, like /404test it gives a 301 to the trailing slash version:

```
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently =>
Server => nginx
Content-Type => text/html
X-Drupal-Cache => MISS
Expires => Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control => no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
ETag => "1349391009"
Content-Language => en
Last-Modified => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 22:50:09 GMT
Location => http://www.angieslist.com/404test/
X-AH-Environment => prod
Vary => Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding => gzip
Content-Length => 20
X-Varnish => 1990526627
Date => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 22:50:09 GMT
Connection => close
```

Then trailing slash version throws the 404:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found =>
Server => nginx
Content-Type => text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Drupal-Cache => MISS
Content-Language => en
ETag => "1349391152-1"
X-Generator => Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Cache-Control => public, max-age=86400
Expires => Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 22:52:32 GMT
X-AH-Environment => prod
X-Varnish => 1990530957
Vary => Cookie
Date => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 22:52:32 GMT
Content-Length => 19329
Connection => close
```

and if you send a HTTP 1.0 request without HOST, you get:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request =>
Server => AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version => 1.0
Content-Type => text/html
Content-Length => 193
Expires => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 22:55:16 GMT
Date => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 22:55:16 GMT
Connection => close
```

So not really sure what to make of that, Very strange...

Comment: Except that Drupal.NET seems to be abandoned.  No updates since 2009.  This isn't saying that they aren't using it, just that it may be that they started with the Drupal.NET CMS and basically forked it, since the Open Source CMS isn't being actively developed.  Which answers the question, but not very satisfactorily, at least in view of considering their CMS for my own project.

Comment: you might just try emailing the IT staff directly. I would understand if they didn't want to say, as to not reveal any exploits that might be possible through a particular CMS, but never hurts to ask.

Comment: AkamaiGHost means that they are using the Akamai CDN to globally cache some or all of their content.